# MSWord Table of contents H1 is formatting right-justified

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, table-of-contents

I've set up "Define New Multilevel List" to allow chapter headings like 1.2.3.4, but I've got one annoying problem in my Table of Contents that I cannot resolve.

[image]

I deleted the TOC and rebuilt it, same issue.  How do I move put he word "Diagrams" below back to the left like all the other headings.